# Git and Obfuscated Code

Tags: php, git, obfuscation

I've been working on an idea, and needed to run it past someone to see if I'd gone off the deep end.

I'm working on a decently complex PHP project, I am the only developer.  We're looking to hire some one else to help with the programming effort, but don't want them to see everything on day one.  There is a pretty clear line between what would be "core architecture" and "non-core".  I'd like the new person to have be able to read and modify the "non-core" section.  The core section is required for the non-core to work.

My plan id this:

1. Make the Core and Non-Core sections separate git repositories
2. Make the Core section a submodule of the Non-Core
3. Add a post-commit hook to the Core repository, to run code obfuscation

Then when the submodule is updated, the files will execute, but will be very hard to read.

#1 and #2 are pretty easy.  But #3... I don't know if it can even be done.  I was looking into the git internals, to see how the files are actually stored, but it seems like they are just stored in the file system.  So there wouldn't be any way to edit them and add obfuscation without totally trashing the "good" copy.  That being said, I could always daisy chain another repo on there.

Good Repo -> Core Repo (with Obfuscation) -> Non-Core

I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

---

Just another thought, but I could not use a repository for the obfuscated code.  Instead have the git commit hook call a script to copy and obfuscate the Core code and place it in the non-core repo.  Add a .getignore so that folder isn't part of the non-core codebase.

Comment: Might be completely off-topic, but you could expose the core functionality as a set of services/APIs.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the idea, but there's a lot of code in there, and I just don't have the time to do a rewrite like that.  I'm still working on switching it all to OOP!

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to do, if there is indeed a "pretty clear line".

Comment: yeah, thanks for the thought, and there is a clear line.  But the core code is more like a collection of objects and functions that the UI is built on top of.

Comment: What's the reason for hiding it from them? If one of complexity, then improve documentation of the core code and have them refer to that instead. If one of trust, why are you hiring someone if you don't trust them?

Comment: what if you just don't give them file permissions to view the folders you don't want them to see?

Comment: It is a trust mostly. Your comment does have some merit, but we spent a lot of time and money developing this code, we really don't just want to hand it out to a new hire without getting to know them first.

Comment: @nathanhayfield I thought about that, but then they wouldn't be able to run locally.

Comment: ah no test server then. you could make a subdomain as a test server

Comment: @nathanhayfield we have a test server, just no remote debugging.

Comment: you could make him/her run all their code on the test server until you trust them. also make them sign a Non-disclosure Agreement

Answer (score 1):

Expose your core functionality as web services and access them over HTTP. Keep the non-core bits in the repository.

Comment: The core code is performance sensitive, like DB connections, tracking, debuging, the added overhead would be too much.  Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: Opinion: IMO, you should trust your developer with the source. It's frustrating to work with someone else's black box; you do you both a disservice hiding it. It will save _you_ time to give them tools to answer any questions. If that's not a compelling argument, then I would second taking this approach: the obfuscation is going to be a real headache. If you access your service _on the same machine that it runs on_, I think you should be fine. Local requests/responses should be handled by the kernel without touching the network.